# bncert says my domain resolves to a different IP address, but it is not

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, https, bitnami

I have this *probably easy* problem:

I'm trying to use `bncert-tool` on my aws wordpress website machine. I transferred my domain from elsewhere to aws, made an hosted zone, also the static ip address.

`nslookup` works, writing the right ip.

[Reading this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59749480/12244676) i went to [www.whatsmydns.net](https://www.whatsmydns.net/) and every query gets an almost all green lights.

Trying to simply reach the website with a browser works: i can see my website normally (except that tls warning).

Can you help me with this? Thank you all.

Comment: **Update** i also changed ip, the dns, and now it's propagated. i thought maybe the dns was messed up... i wasn't probably

Comment: After changing the IP and updating the DNS records, did you manage to generate the SSL certificate using the Bitnami HTTPS configuration tool? Is everything working as expected?

Comment: @JotaMartos Unfortunately no, i didn't. i'm just using it like this while i wait for any reply

Comment: If you still get the error regarding the domain resolution when using the Bitnami HTTPS configuration tool, please ensure all the domains you set when running the tool (both www and non-www domains) are configured using an A record in your DNS provider (whatsmydns.net should resolve the domain only when A record is selected). If the tool continues failing and you are sure everything is configured properly, you can try to run the tool without the validations by running this command: `sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool --perform_public_ip_validation 0 --perform_dns_validation 0`

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this by confirming by myself that everyting was ok, than executing the command setting it to not perfom dns and ip validation.

Comment: I can confirm it works. Tried out like this as in the comment from Jota Martos. `sudo /opt/bitnami/bncert-tool --perform_public_ip_validation 0 --perform_dns_validation 0`

Comment: Tks a lot @ibsenv works for me

Answer (score 5):

This can happen because your hostname resolves to an IPv6 address which is not supported by Bitnami. If `getent hosts <domain>` shows an IPv6 address, this is most likely the problem.

Temporarily remove the IPV6 records from your DNS records and you should be able to run the tool.